# JQuery Timepicker Addon - Can't create TimePicker elements while calling it from an event method

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a small problem with [trentrichardson's jQuery-Timepicker-Addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

Timepicker elements created within `$(document).ready()` are built correctly without problems, and I can do everything from the documentation.

However, when I try to create new elements on a button's `onclick` JavaScript throws the error:

> ```
> TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
> ```

Here's my code (all the following code blocks are inside the same `<script>` element on the page):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hora').timepicker({
      timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
    },$.timepicker.regional['es']); //works correctly, element is generated as desired
  $('#origen_hora_confirmacion').timepicker({
      timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
    },$.timepicker.regional['es']); //works correctly, element is generated as desired
});
```

Later in the same `<script>` element I try to run this code on a button's click event:

```
function agregar_vehiculo() {
  // ...
  $('#fechsalida0').timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
  }); //TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
}
```

And on the button:

```
<input type="button" id="añadirVeh" name="añadirVeh" onclick="agregar_vehiculo()" value="Añadir Vehiculo">
```

What could be the cause of this? Is it the plugin problem or am I missing something about jQuery?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The last code block is called from a button onclick. Can you show the wrapper event listener?

Comment: please show the wrapper code around `$('#fechsalida0').timepicker({...`

Comment: JavaScript Function
`function agregar_vehiculo()
{
  $g_dtDatatable.row.add( [
      $g_szVehiculo,
      '<input class="form-control timenuevos" type="text" name="dateTime_salida[]" id="fechsalida'+$g_iVhFilas+'" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />',
  ] ).draw( false );

  $('#fechsalida0').timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
  }); 
}`

`$g_sz_Vehiculo` is 0 in this case.

Comment: Just a note, buttons aren't meant to be self-closing. Get rid of `/>` at the end of input. Should look like `<input type="button">` without a `/>` at the end

Answer (score 0):

If everything works as expected inside `$(document).ready` you can add the event listener from the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#añadirVeh').click(function () {
    $('#fechsalida0').timepicker({
      timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
    });
  });
});
```

Basically re-write your `agregar_vehiculo` function *inside* of `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. As soon I move existing timepicker code inside this block it ceases to work and console throws `$(...).timepicker is not a function`.

Comment: @GabrielI. replace the `$` with `jQuery`, use `jQuery('#fechsalida0')`