# Why can't I call external functions more than once, after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a follow-up to my previous [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591064/jquery-timepicker-addon-cant-create-timepicker-elements-while-calling-it-from/48591243) that unfortunately I couldn't make it work with the answers provided.

Further testing with external jQuery scripts revelaed to me I can't use the functions more than once in my page, this happens with any external Script such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), [Timepicki](https://github.com/simivar/jquery-timepicky) or [jQuery-Timepicker-Addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

```
//data table init
$g_dtDatatable = $('#example').DataTable();
```

The above code executes fine when called for the first time in `$(document).ready()`. But whenever I try to call it again I get an error.

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

This is *not* an `id` exclusive issue, because if I try to initialize an existing element with a different `id` I get exactly the same error.

This happens with any external .js file. I need to initialize components because I dynamically add new HTML elements to my page.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This behaviour can occur when you load multiple versions of jQuery at different points of the page lifecycle. eg. 1) load first version of jQuery 2) instantiate plugins, such as Datatables 3) load second version of jQuery 4) attempt to interact with previous plugins <- error. This is because the plugins were instantiated on the `$` variable of the first version of jQuery which the second overwrote. ***TL;DR*** - check you aren't using more than one version of jQuery in the page

Comment: If it executes fine the first time around, but then not later then it means something has changed since the page loaded.  Without knowing everything else on the page it's very difficult to answer.  Possibly you're including jQuery twice in the same page, maybe different versions too.  More info is needed.